# Debug a c++ python 3.10 extension, venvlauncher.pdb missing

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I followed [Microsoft excellent tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) to create a Python extension in c++. Everything works fine, I can compile, run and debug the code (both the Python and the C++) in Visual Studio 2022.

However, the issue is that I want do this within a venv, this was possible with Python 3.7.0 but now when I create a venv with Python3.10-64 I can't debug the C++ part.

I have included the `include` and `libs` of the "global Python" in the Visual Studio 2022. Do I miss something when I create the venv with `c:\python310-64\python -m venv venv`? There seems to be a lot less in the `Script` folder now with Python3.10 compared to with Python3.7.

is there anything that I can change within Visual Studio 2022 to hit the C++ breakpoints when I run Python from `venv` created with Python3.10?

When I look at what modules that are loaded when I start the debugging from my venv, and right click to find the symbols for Python.exe it looks like this:
[image].

Compared to this long list when I start the debugging with the "global" Python installation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Woho! I finally figured it out. The `venv` needs to be created with `--symlinks` like this `C:\Python310-64\python.exe -m venv venv --symlinks`. You need to run the command as administrator to get it to work!